# JQueryMobile: Listview filter - How can I get the resulting list?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I dynamically generated my listview. Now, every li element of the listview ul has a specific event due to event binding during the generation of the list. Now this listview data-filter="true".

Then from another textfield(from another jqm page), I need to input a string, on which upon keyup of enter I need to pass the value to the filter fieldtext(the one for filtering of the listview) then get the li elements that corresponds to the passed value.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: you might want to prepare an example http://jsfiddle.net---

Comment: Since the function that I need is probably not visible for those who don't have time to read the whole jqm library, I've implemented my own solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I approach it in a different way:

```
$.each($('#myListView').children(),function(){
    var text = $(this).attr("data-filtertext");
    if(text.toLowerCase().search(search) > 0){
        //do event
        //Since I generate the data-filtertext attr, 
        //and I've guarantee that it wont have duplicate, so: 
        $(this).children("a").click();
    }
});
```